# Do we need to run WinAppDriver server explicitly on the remote server where Jenkins will run my automation?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, appium, winappdriver

As i am very new and doing POC for my project, I am wondering how can i make sure that WinAppDriver server should run before my Automation test in remote server using Jenkins.

Or is it not required to run the WinAppDriver server?

My goal here is that i have a Automation framework which is based on Selenium which test Web Application but due to role based testing i need to change the role of the user to run my role based test case successfully. So for changing the role i need to log in to desktop based application for which i decided to use WinAppDriver API but as i learning that to run the WinAppDriver one needs to run its server so i m wondering:

1. Do i need to run the WinAppDriver Server in the remote server also where my Automation tests run using Jenkins?
2. How can i run the WinAppDriver server in the remote server automatically?

Comment: Drivers are for client system to talk to selenium server which intern talks to the browsers . You need the driver to be running on the system on which test are executing or test can access it

Comment: @PDHide how can i run the WinAppDriver server on the remote server automatically?

Comment: @Ranjit: Were you able to figure that out?